# Using Typescript module augmentation to add to a namespace merged into a class

Tags: typescript

I am trying to augment out-of-date declarations for a third-party Typescript module. The third-party module looks like this:

```js
// third-party-library/index.d.ts
declare module 'third-party-library' {
  class A {
    // ...
  }

  namespace A {
    export type X = string;
    // ...
  }

  exports = A
}
```

I want to add a class to `namespace A`:

```js
// my-app/third-party-library-augmentation.ts
declare module 'third-party-library' {
  namespace A {
    export class B {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding from reading the [TS docs on module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) is that the Typescript compiler should know about `B` in the following code:

```js
// my-app/some-code.ts
import A from 'third-party-library';
import './third-party-library-augmentation';

const b: A.B = new A.B();
```

But this doesn't work, `tsserver` complains that it doesn't know about `B`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're importing the default export, which is the entire module, so you'll have to access the new class like so: `new A.A.B()`. If you want to only import the `A` namespace from the module you can change the import: `import { A } from 'third-party-library'`

Comment: @PaulHuynh hmm-- this gives me the message: [['A' can only be imported by using 'import A = require("A")' or a default import. ]]. Also `A.A` is not defined. The exports of `namespace A` are made available directly as named exports from the module, rather than being nested under named export `A`.